# Creating TypeScript class decorator for log correlation

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-decorator, async-hooks

I'm trying to create a TypeScript decorator that can be added to any class, that will create a request-scoped context that I can use to store a request ID. I've come across a couple of articles around decorators but none seem to fit my use-case.

Below is the code that I use to create the async hook, the decorator and a sample class that should be wrapped. When running the code, the actual response I receive is an empty object. The context is being lost but I'm not following why. I'm not receiving any errors or warnings.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

This is the code I'm using to create the context. Calling the `initContext()` and `getContext()` functions.

```
import * as asyncHooks from 'async_hooks'

const contexts: any = {}

asyncHooks.createHook({
  init: (asyncId: any, type: any, triggerAsyncId: any) => {
    if (contexts[triggerAsyncId]) {
      contexts[asyncId] = contexts[triggerAsyncId]
    }
  }
}).enable()

function initContext(fn: any) {
  const asyncResource = new asyncHooks.AsyncResource('REQUEST_CONTEXT')
  return asyncResource.runInAsyncScope(() => {
    const asyncId = asyncHooks.executionAsyncId()
    contexts[asyncId] = {}
    return fn(contexts[asyncId])
  })
}

function getContext() {
  const asyncId = asyncHooks.executionAsyncId()
  return contexts[asyncId] || {}
}

export { initContext, getContext }
```

This is the decorator that I'm using to wrap the class with. I'm trying to create the constructor within the context of the `initContext` function, set the context ID and then return the new constructor.

```
import { initContext } from './lib/context'

function AsyncHooksContext<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(target: T) {
  return initContext((context: any) => {
    context.id = 'some-uuid-goes-here'

    return class extends target {
      constructor(...args: any[]) {
        super(...args)
      }
    }
  })
}

export { AsyncHooksContext }
```

This is a sample class that should be able to produce the context ID

```
@AsyncHooksContext
class Foo {
  public bar() {
    const context = getContext()
    console.log('This should be the context => ', { context })
  }
}

new Foo().bar()
```

Comment: May be a silly question but this `return contexts[asyncId] || {}` will give an empty object if the id is different, have you tried checking `contexts` directly to see if it gets populated correctly? That would narrow it down to `getContext` instead of the decorator.

Comment: Don't you want to call  `initContext` in the constructor of the instance, not in the class declaration?

Comment: [`runInAsyncScope`](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html#async_hooks_asyncresource_runinasyncscope_fn_thisarg_args) takes a callback and returns `undefined` if a class decorator returns undefined then, by definition the decorator did not replace the class.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen The ID's do get stored in the context correctly. If I wrap the function without the use of the `AsyncHooksContext` it seems to work.